# Custom orderBy sequence on a relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

Laravel version 9.52.9, PHP version 8.2.4

I want to show a list of posts only having group names: *sponsor, featured, boost, ...*

Also, order the posts based on group names: *featured (1st order), boost (2nd order), sponsor (3rd order), ...*

```
// Post Model
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
}

// Group Model
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

**Updated:** As OMR answered.

```
Post::query()
    ->select([
        'posts.id', 'posts.slug', 'posts.created_at',
        'group_id', 'title', 'thumbnail', 'approved_at',
        'groups.name as group_name'
    ])
    ->selectRaw("LENGTH(content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(content, ' ', '')) + 1 AS total_content_word_count")
    ->without('permissions')
    ->join('groups', 'posts.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
    ->whereIn('groups.name', ['sponsor', 'featured', 'boost'])
    ->where('ads', true)
    ->published()
->orderByRaw("FIELD(groups.name, 'featured','boost','sponsor') ASC")
->latest('approved_at')
->paginate(30);
```

**Does anyone know, how I can achieve this on the relationship table?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MySQL FIELD() syntax only works on the same table.

this is not very true

MySQL FIELD() syntax only works on the query tables

to make other table inside query scope, you should join them.

```
Post::query()
    ->select(['posts.id', 'posts.group_id', 'title', 'slug', 'thumbnail', 'approved_at', 'created_at'])
    ->selectRaw("LENGTH(content) - LENGTH(REPLACE(content, ' ', '')) + 1 AS total_content_word_count")
    ->without('permissions')
    ->join('groups', 'posts.group_id', '=', 'groups.id')
    ->whereIn('groups.name', ['sponsor', 'featured', 'boost'])
    ->where('ads', true)
    ->published()
    ->orderByRaw("FIELD(groups.name, 'featured', 'boost', 'sponsor')")
    ->paginate(30);
```